# Displaying a cell value in a text box and moving around in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet which contains some values in the cells A1 to A9. I have a text box and command button 1 (renamed to "previous") and command button 2 (renamed to "Next").

When I click the Next button the values in the cells from A1 to A9 should be displayed in the text box which I have in an order from A1 to A9 and when the Previous button is clicked it should behave in the reverse.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a TextBox and two buttons from AutoShapes.  Enter the following in a **standard module**:

```
Public WhereAmI As Long

Sub Nextt()
    Dim s As Shape
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1")
    If CStr(WhereAmI) = "" Then
        WhereAmI = 1
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("A1").Text
    Else
        If WhereAmI = 9 Then Exit Sub
        WhereAmI = WhereAmI + 1
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Cells(WhereAmI, 1).Text
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Sub Prevv()
    Dim s As Shape
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1")
    If CStr(WhereAmI) = "" Then
        WhereAmI = 2
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("A2").Text
    Else
        If WhereAmI = 1 Then Exit Sub
        WhereAmI = WhereAmI - 1
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Cells(WhereAmI, 1).Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Then assign `Nextt()` to the "Next" button and assign `Prevv()` to the "Previous" button:

[image]

From the above, if you click `Next`, *gamma* will be in the box.  If you click `Previous`, *alpha* will be in the box.

**EDIT#1:**

I use the `Public` variable to keep track of which of the items is currently in the *TextBox*............that way the subs can get to the next or previous value.

All three Shapes *(textbox and two buttons)* are easily available from AutoShapes:

[image]

In my version of Excel, that menu is in the ***Insert*** tab.  When you first start out, there will be nothing in the *TextBox*, that is the reason for the *CStr()* test.

**EDIT#2:**

To handle the case of having the initial value of `WhereAmI` being **0**, use this version of `Prevv()`:

```
Sub Prevv()
    Dim s As Shape
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1")
    If CStr(WhereAmI) = "" Then
        WhereAmI = 2
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("A2").Text
    Else
        If WhereAmI = 1 Then Exit Sub
        If WhereAmI = 0 Then WhereAmI = 2
        WhereAmI = WhereAmI - 1
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Cells(WhereAmI, 1).Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't grasp the use of that `Public` variable and `CStr(WhereAmI)`.  BTW since you're using `Shapes` I guess you're referencing a `TextBox` `Form Control`, but I can't draw it in my Excel 2010: how can you do that?

Comment: @user3598756  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent nice answer.  when pressing next and getting to the last entry it will exit sub, but what if you wanted to go back to the first entry would you just set the variable back to 1?

Comment: @AshtonMorgan  I would keep pressing the `Previous` button to get back to the top..................or you could create a `Reset` button..............

Comment: I succeeded in inserting the _TextBox 1_ `Shape` object and updated my answer to cope with _Form_ Controls as well.   But I also tested your code: the first time pressing "Previous" button starts with `WhereAmI` =0 -> `CStr(WhereAmI)`="0" and finally to `WhereAmI` set to -1 thus resulting to a "run time Error 1004". Moreover the code doesn't take into account any possible starting value of TextBox.

Comment: @user3598756 With **EDIT#2** I removed the `WhereAmI`=0 bug......you are correct that my code completely disregards the contents of the TextBox when performing changes.

Answer (score 1):

**edited**: added **Solution "B"** for Form controls

---

**Solution A** for ActiveX controls

1) double click "Previous" button and VBA gets you in the sheet code pane with

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()'<~~ maybe your "Previous" button was not the 1st ActiveX button you inserted in the sheet so the sub title has a different number in it: don't bother and just keep it as you find it

End Sub
```

that you fill like follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() '<~~ remember: keep the number you already have there in the sub name
    UpdateTextBox 1
End Sub
```

2) double click "Next" button and and VBA gets you in the sheet code pane with

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() '<~~ maybe your "Next" button was not the 2d ActiveX button you inserted in the sheet so the sub title has a different number in it: don't bother and just keep it as you find it

End Sub
```

that you fill like follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()'<~~ remember: keep the number you already have there in the sub name
    UpdateTextBox -1
End Sub
```

3) place this code in any module code pane

```
Option Explicit    

Sub UpdateTextBox(shift As Long)
    Dim found As Range, myRange As Range
    Dim s As OLEObject
    Dim index As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Set s = .OLEObjects("TextBox1") '<~~ set the name of the ActiveX TextBox control
        Set myRange = .Range("A1:A9") '<~~ set the range you want to scroll up and down
    End With

    index = 1 '<~~ default index position should textbox be empty or filled with non valid value
    With myRange
        If s.Object.Value <> "" Then '<~~ get current textbox value index in range
            Set found = .Find(what:=s.Object.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<~~ search for the current text current textbox value index in range
            If Not found Is Nothing Then index = found.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1
        End If

        index = index + shift '<~~ make the shift
        Select Case index
            Case Is > .Rows.Count
                index = .Rows.Count  '<~~ limit max index to range last row
            Case Is < 1
                index = 1 '<~~ limt min index to range first row
        End Select

        s.Object.Value = .Rows(index) '<~~ update textbox value
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Solution B** for Form controls

1) add this in any module code pane

```
Option Explicit

Sub SkipToNext()
    UpdateTextBox2 1
End Sub


Sub SkipToPrevious()
    UpdateTextBox2 -1
End Sub


Sub UpdateTextBox2(shift As Long)
    Dim s As Shape    
    Dim found As Range, myRange As Range
    Dim index As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Set s = .Shapes("TextBox 1") '<~~ set the name of the Form TextBox control
        Set myRange = .Range("A1:A9") '<~~ set the range you want to scroll up and down
    End With

    index = 1 '<~~ default index position should textbox be empty or filled with non valid value
    With myRange
        If s.TextFrame.Characters.Text <> "" Then '<~~ get current textbox value index in range
            Set found = .Find(what:=s.TextFrame.Characters.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<~~ search for the current text current textbox value index in range
            If Not found Is Nothing Then index = found.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1
        End If

        index = index + shift '<~~ make the shift
        Select Case index
            Case Is > .Rows.Count
                index = .Rows.Count  '<~~ limit max index to range last row
            Case Is < 1
                index = 1 '<~~ limt min index to range first row
        End Select

        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = .Rows(index) '<~~ update textbox value
    End With
End Sub
```

2) assign `SkipToNext()` to the "Next" button and `SkipToPrevious()` to the "Previous" button

Comment: Your approach is really nice!